# Is there a word which describes the feeling of wishing you were in an alternative timeline?

Tags: meaning

This one stems from a conversation with a few friends this morning via Telegram, in which one participant posed that question, netting them a few slightly sarcastic responses (*chronodysphoria* being my favourite), but it did get me wondering. *Is* there a word (or succinct phrase) which describes the feeling of wishing you were in an alternative time-line?

Comment: I would seriously doubt this because a) it doesn't come up so often to deserve a phrase and b) as far as we know, it's impossible to be in alternative time-line anyway

Comment: Well, theoretically, M-theory actually would allow for such a scenario to exist, but I do agree it's not something oft discussed by the water cooler. o.o That said, Science Fiction authors have coined words for stranger, more abstract concepts (cyberspace, telesthesia, posthumanism), so it's not _too_ far of a reach. Also, it gives people a chance to suggest one if one definitely doesn't exist. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Closest I could think of would be [Onism](http://www.dictionaryofobscuresorrows.com/post/73524850764/onism), which comes from the Dictionary of Obscure Sorrows. They describe it as

> *n.* the frustration of being stuck in just one body, that inhabits only one place at a time, which is like standing in front of the departures screen at an airport, flickering over with strange place names like other people’s passwords, each representing one more thing you’ll never get to see before you die—and all because, as the arrow on the map helpfully points out, you are here.

Answer (score 1):

Folks who dress or act like they exist in another time in history are called, ***walking anachronisms***. (US)